# npm install without override existing node_module package (custom changes)

Tags: angular, npm

I am developing an angular app with some external package (ex: packageA) but there is an error in that external package and as a work-around I edited node_modules/packageA/somescript.js and after it working fine.

Now when we run npm install then my changes override with actual package script.

I added that node_modules/packageA/ in git and committed but whenever we run npm install it override.

Now I want whenever we run npm install, it will not override my committed changes in node_modules folder, how ?

Comment: npm install always overrides node_module packages. That's it.

Comment: It'd be best to fork the package, fix it, and use your fixed version, then submit a PR and hope it gets merged in a reasonable time.

Comment: thanks @Phix but I don't have time. This is what proper solution but it take time. I am looking for short-term solution to stop this override behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to use a git branch as a dependency... just replace the version of the dependency in your package.json to your repo ex... `"jonchurch/botkit#multi-hears"`

read this article for more info

https://medium.com/@jonchurch/use-github-branch-as-dependency-in-package-json-5eb609c81f1a

for you... It should be something like this

```
"dependencies": {
    "packageA": "yourgithub/reponame#branch-name",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In post, I said

> I added that node_modules/packageA/ in git and committed but whenever
>   we run npm install it override.

but this analysis wrong, actually its not overriding custom changes if we already add in git because whenever npm install run its check package.json packages entry with the node_modules folder and my custom changes is there, so not again downloading from npm and as a result my custom changes not overriding.

Answer (score -1):

Create a folder named `libs` in your repo copy && paste the external package in that and wherever you are using that module import it as `import * as something from '../libs/external_package_name'`. This is the short term solution I can think of right now

If you want a permanent solution fork the package and submit a pr, wait for it to get merged as suggested by @phix

Thanks for the question!

Happy Coding!

Comment: thanks @yaswanthkoneri do you know any article which I can follow for the same.

Comment: @yaswanthkoneri is it possible? can I get some reference on how to do it?